# Getting 'git grep' to work effectively in vim

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

Fugitive.vim allows me to run `git grep` commands; unfortunately, the results are not stored in a quickfix-list, so I need to run `:cw` after a `:Ggrep` in order to have an easily parseable result list.

I would like to type `:Ggr "def my_function"` instead of:

```
:Ggrep "def my_function"
:cw
```

How can I define this `:Ggr` command in my .vimrc file?

EDIT

Once the `:Ggr` command is defined, I can map  to `git grep` on the word under the cursor, which is really awesome:

```
nnoremap <C-F> :Ggr <cword><CR>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [VIM - multiple commands on same line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249275/vim-multiple-commands-on-same-line)

Comment: Note that I will have to pass the argument of :Ggr to :Ggrep... So it's not as simple as running two commands in a row.

Comment: `:Ggrep` does fill the `quickfix` list however the window does not automatically open. Maybe you want the `quickfix` window to open after any grep invocation, `autocmd QuickFixCmdPost *grep* cwindow`, as suggested on the [vim-fugitive FAQ section](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive#faq).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me:

```
:command -nargs=+ Ggr execute 'silent Ggrep!' <q-args> | cw | redraw!
```

Comment: You could have added that as a comment to my answer, since it's only a small tweak to it. Many would consider what you did bad form. At least document the changes and why they are necessary.

Comment: This seems not to be needed anymore. As of 2022, and as per Fugitive's doc, this should be enough:

`command -nargs=+ Ggr execute 'Ggrep! -q' <q-args>`

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `<args>` symbol to insert the arguments given to your custom command:

```
:command -nargs=+ Ggr execute 'Ggrep' <q-args> | cw
```

Note: As the `:Ggrep` command doesn't have the `-bar` argument, it cannot be chained, so `:execute` has to be used.

Comment: This is almost perfect: the Ggrep command opens a window that needs to be closed before the cw command is run, so I have to press <enter> to close it. Any idea how to improve this?

Comment: You can emulate that key press via `... | execute "normal \<CR>" | cw`, or (perhaps easier) try `... | close | cw`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I still have the "Press ENTER of type command to continue" message that is displayed following the :Ggrep command.

Comment: Oh, that hit-enter prompt, not a window; I misunderstood; yeah, that's difficult to avoid.

Comment: Too bad. Your answer is sufficient anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Already mentioned in one of the comments, but I thought the plugin-recommended solution on the fugitive.vim site deserved its own answer:

```
autocmd QuickFixCmdPost *grep* cwindow
```

(from: https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)

Comment: This is correct. However, this requires to press <return> once after the :Ggr command, which is inconvenient.