# How do I search for and then jump to a word in another file in vim

Tags: search, vim

In particular, I'm editing files in Verilog and would like to see other instances of a word under the cursor in other files. Ideally, it'd bring up a list like the auto-complete list. I can then select the line entry and vim would open the file (either in the same window or a new tab).

I've seen this feature in Emacs. I have to think it exists in Vim somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This would be really fun to write in vimscript, but I don't exactly have time at the moment. Hopefully this will get you going in the right direction:

*There is a vim plugin called Fugitive*

It allows you to do things like `git grep`, or `git blame` right from you vim console. https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive

Their `git grep` command, `Ggrep`, should get you a list of local files with whatever word you want to grep for. Possibly check out this Q/A for getting it to work nicely: [Getting 'git grep' to work effectively in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931116/getting-git-grep-to-work-effectively-in-vim)

Last thing I would do is write a little vimscript function and a keystroke alias that would call `Ggrep` with the word under the cursor.

(hopefully I'll have time to write a better answer later)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a tags file available, you might be able to use `:tselect identifier` for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Vimgrep is your friend.

`:vimgrep /pattern/ <path>/**`

This will add lines to the quickfix window. Each line is the text from the line in a file that matches the pattern. The `**` is shorthand for recurse into subdirectories.