# nnoremap command with vim-fugitive

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

This question is inspired by [Getting 'git grep' to work effectively in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931116).

My `.vim/vimrc` entries are similar to those in the question:

```
command -nargs=1 Ggr execute 'silent Git! grep -Win --heading' <q-args>
nnoremap <C-F> :Ggr <cword><CR>
```

The `Ggr` command works. Unfortunately Ctrl-F produces a nasty error:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>33_Git[2].. <SNR>33_Edit[53]..<SNR>33_Edit[36]..<SNR>33_ExecuteInTree:
line    5:
E348: No string under cursor
Error detected while processing function <SNR>33_Git[2]..<SNR>33_Edit[53]..<SNR>33_Edit:
line   36:
E171: Missing :endif
Error detected while processing function <SNR>33_Git[2]..<SNR>33_Edit:
line   53:
E171: Missing :endif
Error detected while processing function <SNR>33_Git:
line    2:
E171: Missing :endif
```

How can I properly define this `nnoremap` in my `.vim/vimrc` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<cword>`works with `expand`, try

```
command -nargs=1 Ggr execute 'silent Git! grep -Win --heading' <q-args>
nnoremap <C-F> :execute 'Ggr '.expand('<cword>')<cr>
```