# How to combine two Vim commands into one (command not keybinding)

Tags: unix, vim, text-editor, neovim

I've found few Stack Overflow questions talking about this, but they are all regarding only the `:nmap` or `:noremap` commands.
I want a command, not just a keybinding. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Use-case:

When I run `:make`, I doesn't saves automatically. So I'd like to combine `:make` and `:w`. I'd like to create a command `:Compile`/`:C` or `:Wmake` to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VIM - multiple commands on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249275/vim-multiple-commands-on-same-line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general information about concatenating Ex command via `|` can be found at [`:help cmdline-lines`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-lines).

You can apply this for interactive commands, in mappings, and in custom commands as well.

Note that you only need to use the special `<bar>` in mappings (to avoid to prematurely conclude the mapping definition and execute the remainder immediately, a frequent beginner's mistake: `:nnoremap <F1> :write | echo "This causes an error during Vim startup!"<CR>`). For custom commands, you can just write `|`, but keep in mind which commands see this as their argument themselves.

[`:help line-continuation`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#line-continuation) will help with overly long command definitions. Moving multiple commands into a separate [`:help :function`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Afunction) can help, too (but note that this subtly changes the error handling).

#### arguments

If you want to pass custom command-line arguments, you can add `-nargs=*` to your `:command` definition and then specify the insertion point on the right-hand side via `<args>`. For example, to allow commands to your `:write` command, you could use

```
:command -nargs=* C w <args> | silent make | redraw!
```

Answer (score 4):

You can combine commands with `|`, see help for `:bar`:

```
command! C update | silent make | redraw!
```

However, there  is a cleaner  way to achieve what  you want.
Just enable the `'autowrite'`  option to automatically write
modified files before a `:make`:

```
                                 'autowrite' 'aw' 'noautowrite' 'noaw'
'autowrite' 'aw'        boolean (default off)
                        global
        Write the contents of the file, if it has been modified, on each
        :next, :rewind, :last, :first, :previous, :stop, :suspend, :tag, :!,
        :make, CTRL-] and CTRL-^ command; and when a :buffer, CTRL-O, CTRL-I,
        '{A-Z0-9}, or `{A-Z0-9} command takes one to another file.
        Note that for some commands the 'autowrite' option is not used, see
        'autowriteall' for that.
```

This option is mentioned in the help for `:make`.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution after a bit of trial and error.

## Solution for my usecase

`command C w <bar> silent make <bar> redraw!`

This is for compiling using make and it prints output only if there is nonzero output.

## General solution

`command COMMAND_NAME COMMAND_TO_RUN`

Where `COMMAND_TO_RUN` can be constructed using more than one command using the following construct.

`COMMAND_1_THAN_2 = COMMAND_1 <bar> COMMAND_2`

You can use this multiple times and It is very similar to pipes in shell.